# how to filter the model we use in model.ForeignKey in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have model in django that has some instaces in itself:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    #some instances...
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    agent = models.ForeignKey("self", verbose_name=('agent'), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

i want to pass only Accounts objects that is_agent set to True in my model.ForeignKey() method.
i don't want to use inheritence for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) for this:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        verbose_name=('agent'),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        limit_choices_to={'is_agent': True}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

i've found the solution:

```
agent = models.ForeignKey("self", verbose_name=('agent'),limit_choices_to={'is_agent': True}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

we should use `limit_choices_to` option